# backend endpoint protection when using front end okta

Tags: reactjs, express, okta

I'm not really sure what to do. I have built a front end SPA using ReactJS and authentication through Okta.

I have each route secure by checking if user is still authenticated via authState and accessToken.

I want to also secure the back end routes/end points in the event someone made direct requests instead of relying on my SPA to do the work.

Is there a way to also use okta in the backend (using expressJS). I know you cannot use the already made Okta SPA configuration as there is no secret key (client authorization).

I know feel like i can also use Okta in the backend. Would I'm just not sure how i would authenticate the request from the front end to the back as technically a user isnt logging in to the backend.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/protect-your-api/nodeexpress/main/